# ReactJs event passed from Container to Presentational Components

Tags: reactjs

Trying to wrap my head around passing events from Container to Presentational components.

As I understand it I attach the event to the Presentational/view level component. But I pass the functionality from the Container component to the Presentational component as a prop. I'm making sure to bind my function to this, but am getting a "Cannot read property 'onMouseEnterHandler' of undefined" error.

How am I not properly passing or binding this function?

```
class FeaturesContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hovered: false
        }
        this.onMouseEnterHandler = this.onMouseEnterHandler.bind(this);
    }
    onMouseEnterHandler() {
        this.setState({
            hovered: true
        })
        console.log('mouse enter, ' + this.state.hovered);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="page features" >
                <ul className="features-list">
                    {data.features.map(function(obj, i) {
                        return (
                            <li key={i}>
                                <Feature {...obj} onMouseEnterHandler={this.onMouseEnterHandler} />
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Feature extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var bgImg = { 
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.props.img + ')'
        };
        return (
            <div className="feature-container" onMouseEnter={this.props.onMouseEnterHandler}>
                <div style={bgImg} className="feature-img"></div>
                <div className="feature">
                    <h4 className="feature-issue">Issue {this.props.issue}</h4>
                    <h1 className="feature-title">{this.props.title}</h1>
                    <h4 className="feature-copy">{this.props.copy}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` inside the `.map` callback is `undefined`. That's why you get an error when trying to access `this.onMouseEnterHandler`.

Either use an arrow function:

```
data.features.map((obj, i) => { ... })
```

or pass `this` as second argument to `.map`:

```
data.features.map(function(obj, i) { ... }, this)
```